# Real world use case of iasc and rank in q kdb

Tags: kdb

I have put lot of efforts to understand and remember iasc and rank of q kdb and searching for opportunities to use them somewhere, can someone please let us know the real world use case of iasc and rank.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort a table `t` by column `c`:  `` t iasc t`c ``

Find row with the the second smallest value in that column: `` t rank[t`c]?1 ``

Answer (score 1):

example of how in this case idesc is used to locate and the pull out the best bid from a book as it changes throughout the day.

```
q)t:([]t:.z.d+10?.z.n;bidPrices:a?\:10f;bidSizes:(a:10?10)?\:100)
q)update  bestBid:bidPrices@'bidIdx, bestBidSize:bidSizes@'bidIdx from update  bidIdx:({first idesc x}each bidPrices) from t
t                             bidPrices                                                                        bidSizes                  bidIdx bestBid  bestBidSize
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019.06.06D02:14:33.894603000 2.993873 1.208589 8.580936 9.179564 3.066645 2.791904 5.504552 5.792775 3.213027 36 68 37 32 37 51 95 13 1 3      9.179564 32
2019.06.06D02:20:21.634713522 0.6212362 6.411941 1.724467 2.80355                                              30 5 70 46                1      6.411941 5
2019.06.06D14:27:48.221686951 3.464977 7.902852 1.751907 9.028504 4.602883 6.513394 5.250004                   33 80 34 12 58 99 25      3      9.028504 12
2019.06.06D06:02:52.488340364 8.667757 1.200717 4.089565 5.700753 0.8786376 4.219038 9.105513 9.069392         94 2 97 57 22 45 53 67    6      9.105513 53
2019.06.06D19:13:19.169877521 0.5447537 3.563764 6.369824 6.462344 6.504396                                    22 67 69 40 26            4      6.504396 26
2019.06.06D13:07:02.008067857 3.478646 2.041581 3.192108 5.685267 4.988226 8.207332 6.44946 3.695111           45 32 82 81 44 11 50 15   5      8.207332 11
2019.06.06D08:28:02.054188480 6.620432 9.094126 2.988477 4.54063 1.56942 0.4699265                             10 68 35 61 91 16         1      9.094126 68
2019.06.06D18:54:38.242827303 9.591257 7.967731 2.641912 3.144961 2.948282 1.954953                            84 90 7 62 89 15          0      9.591257 84
2019.06.06D19:04:44.520627530 8.792454 8.056686 0.9071203 4.778097                                             9 37 23 31                0      8.792454 9
2019.06.06D06:36:31.306959361 7.825156 5.571575 5.040468 3.013724 3.022587 9.058382 0.9598075 7.136615         71 58 40 76 61 80 50 32   5      9.058382 80
q)
```